# Is there a way to make ESLint understand the new import assertion syntax without adding Babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Since the [import assertion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) syntax (e.g. `assert {type: 'json'}`) is mandatory in the latest Node.js versions, I'm looking for a way to be able to write this new syntax, but I don't want to add Babel just to be able to use the Babel ESLint parser which understands it.

Could this be added by a different ESLint plugin?

Comment: That's only a stage 3 proposal so will not yet be included natively in ESLint: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15305

Answer (score 10):

As of this writing, the Node.js core code itself is [configured to use `@babel/eslint-parser` specifically for this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/495825bc18d6260e508fc003b26508591ba4c3ca/.eslintrc.js#L42-L46). It is unlikely that there is an easy and reliable way to do it using a parser shipped with ESLint (at this time). As of February 2023, the [specification is Stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions/). ESLint has a policy of only adding Stage 4 syntax. Additionally, Node.js docs and a runtime warning make it clear that this is an experimental API. Installing `@babel/eslint-parser` is the reasonable solution if you're using an experimental API.

Comment: @Zhe Thanks! I've updated the answer to link to the correct proposal and also updated it to say Stage 2 to keep it current.

Answer (score 10):

You **have** to use the babel eslint parser for that

```
npm i -D @babel/eslint-parser @babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions
```

then in .eslintrc

```json
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "babelOptions": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
      ]
    }
  },
```