# eslint-disable does not work on lines with importing JSON files

Tags: eslint

I've tried `eslint-disable-line` `eslint-disable-next-line` `eslint-disable` - None seem to work when trying to ignore lines that import a JSON file (either with assert or with)

```js
/* eslint-disable-next-line */
import pkg from '../../package.json' assert { type: 'json' };
```

eslint still throws the following error:

`4:38  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token assert`

.eslintrc

```json
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
  }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: ESLint needs to be able to parse the file to start with - otherwise how would it know that's a comment containing a directive for it? Discussion for import assertions: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15305

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make ESLint understand the new import assertion syntax without adding Babel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090960/is-there-a-way-to-make-eslint-understand-the-new-import-assertion-syntax-without)